# extract the value from the log using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Hi I am new to shell script. I am trying to extract the specific value from the log.

When I filter the data by using specific keyword. It looks like these.

```
cat hive-server2.log | grep user
```

The output of the data is

```
2018-01-18T16:20:39,464 WARN  [67272380-f3e9-40da-8e8e-a209c05eb4fe HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-37([])]: util.CurrentUserGroupInformation (CurrentUserGroupInformation.java:getGroupNameFromUser(52)) - user a8197zz (auth:PROXY) via hive (auth:SIMPLE) has no primary groupName, setting groupName to be a8197zz.
```

In the above data I want to extract the specific value for the user like this.

```
a8197zz
```

I tried like this.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "User" }
 /\<user\>/{ u=$10 }
 //{ print u }' OFS=',' hive-server2.log
```

It prints blank lines only. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '[^ ]*(?=\.$)' file
```

or

```
grep -Po 'user \K[^ ]*' file
```

With awk:

```
awk -F "[. ]" '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

or

```
awk -F "user " '{split($2,array," "); print array[1]}' file
```

or search for field with string `user` and print next field:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="user") print $(i+1) }' file
```

Output:

```
a8197zz
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed` command also

```
sed 's/.*user \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/' fileName
```

**Output:**

```
a8197zz
```

Comment: I'd suggest `sed -n '/user/s/.*user \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p' fileName` to avoid getting spammed with the lines not containing "user".

Comment: @daniu, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/\./,"",$NF);print $NF}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a8197zz
```